# Can you fire an event when a socket.io room empties?

Tags: socket.io

Background: I'm making an extremely basic multiplayer online game server where each game is contained in it's own room and its game data (including its room name) in a GAMES array and I want to remove the game data from the array when the room no longer exists.

I'm hoping theres something like this tht

```
socket.io.rooms.on('disconnect', function(roomID){
 //PSEUDO CODE// 
 //delete GAMES.getby(gameID:roomID)//
});
```

Otherwise I plan on looping through the games array and comparing the room names against io.sockets.manager.rooms data when a socket disconnects and deleting any inconsistencies. But I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.sockets.clients('room')` will give you a list of sockets currently in a room, so you could do something like:

```
if(io.sockets.clients('room').length > 1){
     //delete room logic here
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Should be `<`, but SO doesn't let me make edits of fewer than 6 characters.